# How to retrieve data from SQL Server database into the application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am creating a web app using Razor pages in ASP.NET Core. How can I retrieve data from my database? I am trying to connect my database with the application.

```
[Table("Employee")]
public class Employee
{
  [Key]
  public Guid EmployeeId { get; set; }
  [Required]
  [StringLength(50)]
  public string Name { get; set; }
  [Required]
  [StringLength(100)]   
  public string Address { get; set; }
  public byte Status { get; set; }
}
```

This is how the models look which is auto-created after running the command `scaffold-DbContext`.

How can I retrieve data from the DB?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/working-with-dbcontext#lifetime

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: [Razor Pages with Entity Framework Core in ASP.NET Core - Tutorial 1 of 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/intro?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: This question is way too broad for stack overflow. This is not a beginner tutorial site. I vote close

Answer (score 2):

You only create your model. You had already created the database, please skip step 6.

To retrieve data from an existing database in EF Core, you should do the following step:

**1. Create an App**

Create an ASP.NET Core app .NET 6.

Install the following NuGet packages:

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 6
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 6

**2. Create the Models**

Create a model for your existing SQL Server database. You can create the model by `Scaffold-DbContext` command or manually.

To create models from existing SQL Server database use `Scaffold-DbContext` command:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=WebAPI;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

In Visual Studio, the commands is typed in *Package Manager Console*.

The model could be created manually as follow:

```
public class Employee
{
  [Key]
  public Guid EmployeeId { get; set; }
  [Required]
  [StringLength(50)]
  public string Name { get; set; }
  [Required]
  [StringLength(100)]   
  public string Address { get; set; }
  public byte Status { get; set; }
}
```

You have done this step.

**3. Create a Context**

If you used `Scaffold-DbContext` command, the dbContext was created automatically. The name of the db context class is `[Your Database Name]Context`. In this example is `WebAPIContext`.

You could also create db context class manually as follow:

```
public class WebAPIContext: DbContext
{
   public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

**4. Configure database connection**

Add the following code to `appsettings.json` file

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=WebAPI;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
```

**5. Add AddDbContext service**

Add the following code to `Program.cs` file

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext(options =>
                   options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))
                   , optionsLifetime: ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
```

**6. `Add-Migration` and `Update-Database` command**

Use the `Add-Migration init1` command to scaffold a migration to apply these changes to the database.

Run the `Update-Database` command to apply the new migration to the database.

**Remark:** If you have not created the database, you should do step 6.

Now you can retrieve data from SQL database and make `CRUD` operations on your database.

To list employees, replace the following code in the Razor page:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
   private readonly WebAPIContext _context;
   public IndexModel(WebAPIContext context)
   {
      _context = context;
   }

   public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

   public async Task OnGetAsync()
   {
      Employees = _context.Employees.ToList();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have great tutorial in answer above, first of all check key aspects:

1. have you made connection to Db? (DB Context)
2. is Db connection string correct (in appsettings.json)
3. have you registered DbContext in services in Startup.cs to use in Dependency Injection
4. are you properly using db context in other classes - you can compare with tutorial approach to db context

cheers